# Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed uniquely as a disjoint union of open intervals. Does this generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology

I know that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed uniquely as a disjoint union of open intervals. Further, only countably many intervals feature in any such decomposition.

Supposing we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, and 'open intervals' with 'open connected subsets,' does the above result still hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The components of $U$ are open in $U$, and hence in $\mathbb{R}^n$, by the local connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n$. (In fact, this condition is equivalent to the local connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n$; local connectedness is the key word here!)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ah thank you. So the result holds in any locally connected topological space? *Edit.* Apart from the countability requirement, of course.

Comment: Yes @user18921 and you're welcome!